# Executing the script one time in each folder

Tags: python, scripting

I need to make a script that executes a script one time in each folder of a directory.

Script in question:

```
f = open('OrderEXAMPLE.txt', 'r')
data = f.readlines()
mystr = ",".join([line.strip() for line in data])
with open('CSV.csv', 'w') as f2:
f2.write(mystr)
```

With this script, it changes a list of customer data into csv form.

Each order form has its own folder, so my intial thought was to put the same script into each folder. From there, write another script that executes each script simultaneously.

Folder structure is like so:

Order_forms

--Order_123

-----Order_form

--Order_124

-----Order_form

Amateur at python, so advice is needed and appreciated.

Comment: Instead, just iterate through each folder and write the csv data as you go. Use `os.walk()`.

Comment: @BobDylan Can you show me an example? or point me at a link?

Comment: [os.walk()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.walk)

Comment: Why is the first part of the script commented out? Doesn't make sense. That is the better way of doing it.

Comment: @BobDylan Oops sorry, I just copied and pasted my code. I'll edit, thanks

Comment: Do you need separate CSV's under each folder or is one large CSV the goal? You have not clearly explained the desired output.

Comment: I gave a concept for separate csv's for each file. Not sure if that's what you want or not but it shows how to walk through. Not sure why you'd want that but it is an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just walk the directory structure with one script. This will write a separate CSV for each file with the name `<original_filename>_CSV.csv`. Without more clarity on the desired output nor knowing what the data looks like I can't help much more. You should be able to tweak this for whatever you need.

```
import os

parent_folder = 'Order_forms'
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(parent_folder):
    for f in files:
        with open(os.path.join(root, f), 'r') as f1:
            data = f1.readlines()
            mystr = ",".join([line.strip() for line in data])
            with open(os.path.join(root, '{}_CSV.csv'.format(f)), 'w') as f2:
                f2.write(mystr)
```

Comment: I'm just trying different things to get to my desired outcome. Thanks for you comments!

Comment: @SammyChristoff well if this is helpful, please upvote it (conversely, if it is not, downvote it and preferably explain why). If it solves the problem, accept it as the answer so others don't waste any time on it.